# how to update listitem(observableObject) in Listview(observerableCollection) in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a collection of instruments, and I'd like to configure each of them after I add them to a list

Currently this instrument is defined as a class inherited from ObservableObject, and stored in an ObservableCollection, shown as a Listview with a datatemplate of instrument details.

Now I can add/delete an instrument. but when I try to update instrument details(e.g. names, type). it is not update to instrument class property.

I'm using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm, I tested that it will work if I just put an instrument details in textbox as the direct element in the mainwindow, but not work as listviewitem.
So does it mean that I can't put observableObject under another observableObject/ObserverbaleCollection?

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView_Instr" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding InstrumentConfigs, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectInstrumentConfig, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  Padding="5,5,5,5" Grid.Row="0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=ListView_Instr}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox_InstrChecked" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label Content="Type"/>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_InstrType" ItemsSource="{Binding InstrTypes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2">
                            <Label Content="Name"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_InstrName" Text="{Binding InstrName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="3">
                            <Label Content="Addr"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_InstrAddr" Text="{Binding InstrAddr, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="4">
                            <Label Content="Interface"/>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_InstrInterface" ItemsSource="{Binding InstrInterfaceTypes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Any detail I missed when using Observable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following way should work.

Instrument.cs

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace wpf_binding
{
    [INotifyPropertyChanged]
    public partial class Instrument
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string name;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string description;

        partial void OnNameChanged(string value)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Name changed: {Name}");
        }

        partial void OnDescriptionChanged(string value)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Description changed: {Description}");
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace wpf_binding
{
    [INotifyPropertyChanged]
    public partial class ViewModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<Instrument> instruments;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private Instrument selectedItem;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Instruments = new ObservableCollection<Instrument>()
            {
                new Instrument() { Name = "Item 1", Description = "Desc 1" },
                new Instrument() { Name = "Item 2", Description = "Desc 2" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="wpf_binding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_binding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Instruments}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Name:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Description:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Description}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace wpf_binding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use `CommunityToolkit`, add the `[ObservableObject]` attribute to the partial class, because it will automatically implement both `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanging` interfaces. And instead of `System.Console` use `System.Diagnostics` with `Debug.WriteLine` in WPF. I think `Console` is used in WinForms (as I remember)